# Nested Conditions in Mongquery

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In one code i had the following filter Definition (`filter` is a instance of `FilterDefinitionBuiler<T>` )

```
  filter = Filter.And(
  Filter.Eq(x => x.CompanyId, companyId),
  Filter.Eq(x => x.DepartureProviderUniqueValue, departureValue),
  Filter.Eq(x => x.ArrivalProviderUniqueValue, arrivalValue),
```

Now If a condition is met I want to extend the query I did it like this

```
if(date > DateTime.Min)
{
     filter= Filter.And(filter, Filter.Eq(x => x.DepartureDate, date));
}
```

but When I run the query it behaves  like the first conditions were concated with an OR instead of a AND. I would understand it would behave like a nested clause, but as all conditions are connected with AND.

Any explanations? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Boas, I can't reproduce this. It always comes out as an conjunction for me. Could you call `filter.Render(BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>(), BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry)` and provide the string output of the result?